# In PHP how do I decrement quantity of multiple items by 1 when these items are ordered?

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is the code which I have used; the problem is only 1 item's
     quantity can be decremented at a time; multiple item quantities cannot
     be decremented.

```
 <?php


    $dbhost = "localhost"; 
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbdb = "yumyum";


    $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error");


    mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die("database selection error");


    $id = $_POST['id'];


    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

        $output = $r['Quantity'];


            echo $output;
            $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` LIKE ".$r["id"]);
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
$query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` = '".$r["id"]."' ");
```

OR

```
        $query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` = '".$r["id"]."' ");
        $rows = array();

        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

             $output = $r['Quantity'];      

             $output = $output-1;
             $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = '".$output."' where  `food`.`id` = '".$r["id"]."' ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its sending one id at a time after $id = $_POST['id'];

you only need to do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` = $id");
```

and remove all other lines underneath it.

Comment: The problem with your statement is that the `IN` clause's SELECT can only have 1 field.  So change the $subQuery select to `SELECT id FROM....`

Comment: @Qambar Raza doesnt say anything it does not update multiple items quantities

Comment: If your id is an integer i believe we should use this as subQuery

`SELECT id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` = $id`

Comment: how do ichange this part accordingly?



while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

    $output = $r['Quantity'];

        //encode the returned data in JSON format
        echo $output;
        $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` LIKE ".$r["id"]);

Comment: @QambarRaza any mor suggestions?

Comment: can you do var_dump( $id ); and tell me what exactly are you getting from $_POST['id'] ?

Comment: @QambarRaza id is the details i obtain when i use my android app to order items

Comment: i need to see the exact data, what i want to know is if its one id like 96 or is it an array [96,23,42,23]. because from what i see it looks like only one id for which you don't need a subQuery.

Comment: @QambarRaza where do i place var_dump( $id ); ?

Comment: @QambarRaza how to do without sub query?

Comment: @QambarRaza Bro any more suggestions?

Comment: Place it after this statement => $id = $_POST['id']; var_dump($id); and copy paste the text you see on the page.

Comment: @QambarRaza There is no text on the page since it happens via android app

Comment: In that case you will have to first confirm if your data is being posted from android properly or not. And you will need to print the data on your eclipse console which will be the value of var_dump from PHP.

Comment: @QambarRaza i get null

Comment: Then the problem is in your android app. It is not sending any id to PHP. Fix that and then review the PHP code.

Comment: @QambarRaza it is sending one id at a time

Answer (score 0):

chech no# of records after record query. For example for your code,

```
  <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost"; 
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbdb = "yumyum";


    $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error");

    mysql_select_db($dbdb) or die("database selection error");

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE $id");
    echo mysql_num_rows($query1); // this will show you count of records by above select query make sure you have more than one item count to update multiple record. 
    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {

        $output = $r['Quantity'];
        echo $output;
        $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE food SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 where  `food`.`id` LIKE ".$r["id"]);
}

?>
```

if you are geeting 1 record in select query then use wild cards in your query like,

```
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT Quantity,id FROM `yumyum`.`food` where  `food`.`id` LIKE '%".$id."%'");
```

try to use wildcard according to your DB structure.

Comment: what count you got in output ?, on printing mysql_num_rows

Comment: If you can paste them it will be easy to solve them.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\yumyum\reserve.php on line 1

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\yumyum\reserve.php on line 15

Comment: I have updated my code a typo was there please try it now ... and share result